# Side by side items with images using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to display images side by side using just css.  The problem is that the images are not displaying inline but as a list (I am using the `<ul>` tag to accomplish this).  Maybe I am using the wrong type of tag or my css is just wrong (see below):

```
ul {
    float: left;
    width: 15em; /* width is changed */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20%;
}
```

Comment: If you provide the (X)HTML markup, we can give a more precise answer.

Comment: ul.gallery { height:425px; width:200px; list-style-type: none; } ul.gallery li { border:1px solid #BBBBBB; float:right; height:50px; margin-right:7px; margin-top:7px; width:50px; } </style> </head> <body> <h2>Header Here</h2> <ul class="Gallery"> <li>Link with image here</li> </ul>

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
ul.gallery {
   height:425px;
   width:200px;
   list-style-type: none;
}
ul.gallery li {
   border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
   float:right;
   height:50px;
   margin-right:7px;
   margin-top:7px;
   width:50px;
}
```

And the (x)html

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li><img src="images/0001.jpg" /></li> 
    <li><img src="images/0001.jpg" /></li> 
    <li><img src="images/0001.jpg" /></li> 
    <li><img src="images/0001.jpg" /></li> 
    <li><img src="images/0001.jpg" /></li> 
    <li><img src="images/0001.jpg" /></li> 
    <li><img src="images/0001.jpg" /></li> 
    <li><img src="images/0001.jpg" /></li> 
    <li><img src="images/0001.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I believe the author's problem stems from having the li width set to 100%. This should take care of that.

Comment: Hi,

My content is dynamic.  Will this change this?

Thanks in advance,
Ray

Comment: What do you mean ?
Even if your content is dynamic, it should fit to your needs.
But if you want something more specific, you should give a piece of your code and more precisions on what you want to get and from what/where.

Comment: By the way, you can add as much images (tags) as you want to the html i provided.
Just set your width/height to fit your needs.

Comment: Sorry about that...  Here are some more detail.

I am creating a simple list of images that ref another page.  I wish to place my list of images side by side with the title of the location above it.

ul.gallery {
height:425px;
width:200px;
list-style-type: none;
}
ul.gallery li {
border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
float:right;
height:50px;
margin-right:7px;
margin-top:7px;
width:50px;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<h2>Header Here</h2>
<ul class="Gallery">
<li>Link with image here</li>
</ul>

Comment: Here is the link to the page to see what the above code is doing...  

http://www.buzzworthytravel.com/WorldDestinations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not use span tags rather than ul/li? Using the list tags is probably why you're getting a list.

Comment: span should not be used to do this.
Maybe he wants to use a list because it is semanticly correct for his purpose.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to do this?

```
ul
 li  img 1 /li
 li  img 2 /li
/ul
```

if so, your css should be on the li element

```
li { display:block float:left padding: 0 margin: 0} 
ul { padding:0 margin 0;}
```

Comment: I need to clarify a bit..  my content is also dynamic.. not sure if that makes a difference